# A function F from X to Y is continuous if and only if F is continuous to F(X)

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Today I read in my topology book that a function F from X to Y is continuous if and only if F is continuous to F(X). My question is this: Let K be a closed subset of X and Suppose there is a continuous function F from K to (-1,1). So (-1,1) is F(K). Let Y be [-1,1]. Because that function F from X to Y is continuous if and only if F is continuous to F(X), The origin of [-1,0] should be a closed subset of K. But the origin of [-1,0] is exactly the same as the origin of (-1,0] which isn't necessarily closed. I obviously missing here an important detail.(The reason I ask this question is because of the Tietze extension theorem.)

By the way, how can I write with mathematic notations? It would really help me to write more formally and clear.

Comment: For writing mathematics there is a basic MathJax tutorial and reference [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: $(-1,0]$ **is** a closed subset of the space $(-1,1)$.

Comment: Thank you, now I see it. (-1,0] is an intersection of a closed subset in R with (-1,1).

Comment: Yes, exactly. You’re welcome.

Answer (score 1):

It's useful to think of the "nice pullbacks for open sets" definition of continuity: $f:X \to Y $ is continuous if for every open set $U \subset Y$, $f^{-1}(U)$ is an open set in the $X$ (where here $f^{-1}$ denotes the *set* inverse, i.e.,
$$
f^{-1}(U) = \{x \in X \mid f(x) \in Y \}.
$$

Now suppose that $F : X \to F(X) \subset Y$ is continuous. Then for any open set $U$ in $F(X)$, we have $F^{-1}(U)$ is open.

Now suppose that $U'$ is an open set in $Y$. I'd like to show that $F^{-1}(U')$ is open in $X$.

Well, $K = U' \cap F(X)$ is open in $F(X)$ by the definition of the subset topology. So $F^{-1}(K)$ is open, by continuity from $X \to F(X)$.

And $F^{-1}(K) = F^{-1}(U')$ [Why? I leave you to work that out...]. So $F^{-1}(U')$ is open in $X$ for an arbitrary open set $U' \subset Y$. Hence $F: X \to Y$ is also continuous.

---

All this can be converted into the closed-sets definition for continuity, and you can use to see where your mistake is (if you so choose). The key error is, I suspect, what Brian Scott pointed out, namely, that you need to better understand how the subspace topology is defined.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer, you helped me a lot!